# Joomla component keep form view on submit

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.3

I've been basically following [the joomla guide](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Example_of_a_frontend_update_function) for a front end form, but I'm having trouble understanding how to keep my form view once submitted.  I'm getting data back, but it's from my controller and just replaces the form.  This isn't a DB update, it's pulling data from an API that should be shown below the form... but I don't see how to do that based on the guide.

Sorry, I feel like this is a dumb question, I'm just not used to MVC yet.  Maybe someone can point out a better guide for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out a way around it.  I'm using JQuery to get the results in a div.